# Split the string in most efficient manner

Tags: java, android, regex, optimization

I am creating an android application. I have multiple strings, one of which is

```
[
  {
    "name": "lofer",
    "fbname": "\u200b \u179c",
    "link": "http:\/\/example.com:9874\/et\/oyp.pls",
    "0": null
  },
  {
    "name": "oxypo",
    "fbname": "\u200b \u179c\u17b7",
    "link": "http:\/\/example.com:9874\/et\/pou.pls",
    "0": null
  }
]
```

This is stored in `String result`

Now I want to extract from this string is the names and respective links like

```
Name1= lofer
Link1= http://example.com:9874/et/oyp.pls

Name2= oxypo
Link2= http://example.com:9874/et/pou.pls
```

First I am removing all the double quotes then I remove "**[**" from the start and "**]**" from the end and then I split by "**}**" then I am removing "**{**" and then splitting each by "**,**" and then I find name and link.

I have written a code and its working perfectly fine, I am getting what I want but I want to optimize it. Here is my code and what I am doing

```
result=result.replace("\"","");
    result=result.substring(1,result.length()-1);
    String [] split=result.split("\\}");       
        for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
        {
            split[i]=split[i].substring(1);
            String [] spl=split[i].split(",");
            Data d = new Data();
            for(int j=0;j<spl.length;j++)
            {                                   
                if(spl[j].substring(0,4).equals("name"))
                {
                    d.name=spl[j].substring(5);
                }
                else if(spl[j].substring(0,4).equals("link"))
                {
                    d.link=spl[j].substring(5);
                    d.link=d.link.replace("\\", "");
                }               
            }
             output.add(d);
            Log.i("name",d.name);
            Log.i("link",d.link);
        }
```

I am not good at regular expressions and maybe we can achieve all this with regular expression or with anything but **OPTIMIZATION** is my main concern here instead of replacing multiple times. Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That is JSON. You may want to look into a JSON parser.

Comment: Ok thanks will look into it and get back to you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [JSON](http://json.org).

Android comes with basic [JSON parsing classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) and there are other libraries available (e.g. Gson, Jackson) that offer greater feature sets.

The most basic solution to your problem using the classes provided with Android is:

```
// Your JSON represents an array of objects
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(yourString);

// Now you have the array, iterate and get the objects
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    System.out.println("Name" + i + "= " + obj.getString("name"));
    System.out.println("Link" + i + "= " + obj.getString("link"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JSON the efficient way is to use `JSON parser` like `GSON`

Comment: I didn't somebody else did. I am looking into it will upvote if it helps me

Comment: sure no issue dear @Hamza .if you talk about efficent way parser will be the best,always try to use generic way

Comment: Yes that is why I asked this question because I was clueless

Comment: @Hamza go ahead with json parser